# How to convert date into unix time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I have a date that looks like this?

Sun, Nov 14, 2021 04:52:00PM

How can I convert this into unix time?

I did new Date('Sun, Nov 14, 2021 04:52:00PM')
and .getTime() to it however i get returned NaN?

Is there a way of doing this moment or js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With momentjs you can use the `ddd, MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss` pattern:

```js
const d = "Sun, Nov 14, 2021 04:52:00PM"

const parsed = moment('Sun, Nov 14, 2021 04:52:00PM',
                      'ddd, MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate()
console.log(parsed)
console.log('unix:', parsed.getTime())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```